# line-height: 100% still makes h1 and div trim part of the letters?

Tags: html, css

`line-height: 100%` should set the line height to be same as the font size, right?

At least the answer should be yes for `a` tag and `span` tag, but not for `div` and `h1`.

```
<style>
h1, span, div, a {
  font-family: Arial;
  line-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: black;
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
</style>

<h1>Testing: gjpqy</h1>
<a href="#">gjpqy testing</a><br><br>
<div>gjpqy testing</div><br>
<span>gjpqy testing</span>
```

[JS Fiddle for testing the code above](https://jsfiddle.net/6xtdhk3e/2/)

You can see that some lower part of letters 'gjpqy' got trimmed away. The problem happens on all IE, Chrome and Firefox. Setting a to a larger line-height like 110% is not an option, as the font size will be varying in actual use, and an exact fit is needed.

Did I miss anything in CSS? How can I set a line height to be exactly the same as font?

Comment: If you don't set a line-height value then it appears fine.

Comment: why not to give `line-height:normal;` or give it's value in `numbers` like `line-height: 1.4;` ? the percentage value might not be giving it the complete height.

Comment: `line-height: 1` also gives the same problem. `line-height:normal` is a working workaround on Chrome, but that leaves the user agent determine what is "reasonable", which some user agent may say that having some space is "reasonable", where I don't want spaces.

Comment: "line-height: 100% should set the line height to be same as the font size, right?" Right. But the height of the glyphs for many fonts is greater than the font-size, so the glyphs get trimmed. You need to set the line-height to the ratio of font ascent+descent / em square height, which you can obtain by inspecting the font metrics.

Answer (score 2):

You could try,

```
line-height: normal;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6xtdhk3e/5/

Comment: `auto` is not a viable property for `line-height`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant normal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`line-height: normal`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) which is the default:

> **line-height: normal**
>
> Tells user agents to set the used value to a "reasonable" value based
>   on the font of the element.

This leaves it up to the browser to determine the optimal line height based on factors such as font family, style and weight.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nashcheez/6xtdhk3e/6/

Modified code:

```css
h1,
span,
div,
a {
  font-family: Arial;
  line-height: normal;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: black;
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Testing: gjpqy
</h1>

<a href="#">gjpqy testing</a><br><br>
<div>gjpqy testing</div><br>
<span>gjpqy testing</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
line-height: inherit;
```

[click here to check](https://jsfiddle.net/qwb98v6o/1/)

Answer (score -1):

What about padding-bottom?

see: https://jsfiddle.net/6xtdhk3e/4/

```
h1, span, div, a {
  line-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: black;
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: No, this is not acceptable. The font size will be varying in actual use, so it must be relative to the font-size instead of a hard code value.

Comment: your font-size is fixed... "font-size: 50px;"

Comment: That is for demonstration only. In actual use, that part will be set by backend (PHP to be exact)